# How to Reduce Clickable Area of Links in Css

Tags: html, css

My website has sections with headers to divide them. Below each header are rows of images. When the header is clicked it only shows images in that section. I want to have the clickable area of the header link consist of the text and its background color. I have assigned the header and link tags in CSS to a max-width. The clickable area does not go beyond the top or bottom but extends past the sides. How can I reduce the clickable area to just the text and its background color without the images and header itself being moved?

Here is my CSS

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 275px;
    max-width: 275px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: right;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #e83a3a;
    max-width: 275px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: Place the heading in a div, and give the div a certain size. Then, omit the width, margin, etc. from the heading's CSS (and the `a`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the heading inline-block will cause its width to collapse down to only as small as necessary:

```css
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This can affect placement of other elements in some cases, in which placing it within a div and making the div's width `100%` will fix this (shouldn't be necessary, but depends on your site's layout).

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying to figure this out for the past couple hours.

Answer (score 0):

use a element for the text, like a span, and link the span instead of the whole element. you can center the span (or whatever you use) with flexbox, or just `margin: auto;` in CSS. make the parent container's background image the image you want to display. this will work.